# Ao clicar em um botão, é enviado o value para um imput text

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Olá, como faço e qual seria melhor forma PHP, javascript, tenho 20 botões cada um com um numero, gostaria de fazer o seguinte: Quando alguém clicasse em um dos botões por exemplo botão 1, ele vai abrir outra pagina com formulário onde consta um campo imput text com nome de Numero da Sacola nesse campo fosse adicionado o valor desse botão no caso numero 1: vou anexa 2 imagem para explicar melhor e o código.

[image: Segunda tela, formulário]

[image: Primeira tela,Números das sacolas]

```html
<?php session_start();
include_once 'includes/header.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/menu.inc.php';
?>

<!-- Formulário de Cadastro Cliente -->
        <div class="row container">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <fieldset class="formulario" style="padding: 5px">
                    <legend><img src="imagens/sacola.png" alt="[imagem]"style="width:80px; height:45px"></legend>
                    <br>
                    
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])):
                            echo $_SESSION['msg'];
                            session_unset();
                        endif;
                    ?>
                    
                    <!-- Botões -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <div class="linha1">
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="01">01</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="02">02</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="03">03</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="04">04</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="05">05</a>          
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="linha2">
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="06">06</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="07">07</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="08">08</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="09">09</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="10">10</a>          
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="linha3">
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="11">11</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="12">12</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="13">13</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="14">14</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="15">15</a>          
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="linha4">
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="16">16</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="17">17</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="18">18</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="19">19</a>
                            <a href="emprestimo.php" class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px"value="20">20</a>          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </fieldset>
        </div>
        
        
<?php include_once 'includes/footer.inc.php';?>
<?php include_once 'includes/script.inc.php';
```

Código tela Empréstimo

```html
<?php session_start();
include_once 'includes/header.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/menu.inc.php';
?>

<!-- Formulário de Cadastro Cliente -->
        <div class="row container">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <form action="banco_de_dados/create.php" method="post" class="col s12">
                <fieldset class="formulario" style="padding: 5px">
                    <legend><img src="imagens/sacola.png" alt="[imagem]"style="width:80px; height:45px"></legend>
                    <br>
                    
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])):
                            echo $_SESSION['msg'];
                            session_unset();
                        endif;
                    ?>
                    
                    <!-- Campo Nome -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" maxlength="40" required autofocus>
                        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                    </div>
                                        
                    <!-- Campo Telefone -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
                        <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" maxlength="13" required>
                        <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
                    </div>
                    
                   <!-- Campo Cpf -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">credit_card</i>
                        <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" maxlength="14" required>
                        <label for="cpf"> CPF</label>
                    </div>
                   
                                      <!-- Campo Sacola -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
                        <input type="text" name="numero" id="cpf" maxlength="2" required>
                        <label for="numero">Número da Sacola</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">timelapse</i>
                            <select>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Período</option>
                                <option value="1">Manhã</option>
                                <option value="2">Tarde</option>
                                <option value="3">Noite</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                   
                    <!-- Botões -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input type="submit"style="width:120px; height:37px" value="Empréstimo" class="btn blue">
                        <input type="submit"style="width:120px; height:37px" value="Devolução" class="btn red">
                        <input type="reset" style="width:120px; height:37px" value="limpar" class="btn lilac">
                    </div>
                    
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div> 

<?php include_once 'includes/script.inc.php';?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de um link, poderia ter botões mesmo, e cada botão poderia ter um atributo `data-numero` com o número do botão e também um `id` igual para todos esses botões, ex:

```
<button id="botao" data-numero="01">01</button>
<button id="botao" data-numero="02">02</button>
```

Dai é só capturar o evento de click no botão e redirecionar para `emprestimos.php` passando uma query string com o numero do botão ex:

```
//pega todos os botoes
const botoes = document.querySelectorAll('#botao');

for (let i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) {
    //escuta o evento de click em cada botao
    botoes[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        //pega o numero do botao clicado
        const numeroSacola = this.dataset.numero;

        //redireciona para emprestimos.php passando o numero do botao
        window.location.href = `emprestimos.php?numeroSacola=${numeroSacola}`;
    });
}
```

e no seu `emprestimo.php` é só usar a superglobal `$_GET` pra pegar o número da sacola passado na query string:

```
<label>Numero da Sacola</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['numeroSacola']) ? $_GET['numeroSacola'] : null; ?>"/>
```

Comment: Primeiro obrigado pela atenção e pela resposta, estou me batendo para aprender e quase sempre utilizo os métodos errados como os link que você comentou, fiz da forma que você passou e quase consegui eu acho rsrs, mudei de link no botão para botão mesmo, porem ele esta dando algo errado, ele pega o numero do botão clicado mas não estou entendo a parte do numeroSacola que não passa para o campo, vou postar o erro e o código como você passou.

Comment: user156561 Muito obrigado mesmo, era bem isso que estava tentando, nessa segunda tentativa que não estava dando certo era apenas o nome da pagina que estava colocando emprestimos.php e na verdade é emprestimo.php, novamente muito obrigado...

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tela de empréstimo

```html
<!-- Campo Sacola -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
                        <label>Numero da Sacola</label>
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['numeroSacola']) ? $_GET['numeroSacola'] : null; ?>"/>
                    </div>
```

Tela sacola

```html
<!-- Botões -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <div class="linha1">
                            <button id="botao" data-numero="01"class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px">01</button>
                            <button id="botao" data-numero="02"class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px">02</button>
                            <button id="botao" data-numero="03"class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px">03</button>
                            <button id="botao" data-numero="04"class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px">04</button>
                            <button id="botao" data-numero="05"class="btn blue" style="width:120px; height:37px">05</button>                
                        </div>
```

Script

```html
<script>
            //pega todos os botoes
            const botoes = document.querySelectorAll('#botao');

            for (let i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) {
                //escuta o evento de click em cada botao
                botoes[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    //pega o numero do botao clicado
                    const numeroSacola = this.dataset.numero;

                    //redireciona para emprestimos.php passando o numero do botao
                    window.location.href = `emprestimos.php?numeroSacola=${numeroSacola}`;
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: user156561, sera que tem alguma forma de enviar para o banco esse valor que foi passado do botão para o formulário, quando tento enviar ele vai sempre com valor zero 0